# What is the "main widget" in QT?

Tags: qt, widget

I've seen the main widget referenced in a few QT docs. Does this simply refer to the first widget created after QApplication?

If so, is it automatically the widget to which all user events are sent by default?

If not, could you explain what i'm missing?

Comment: It really depends on the context in which the term is being used. The answers below are essentially all valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt, any parentless widget is a top-level window by default. Any widget type could be your "main" window. You can have more than one. It's a convention, not a technicality.

[QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) incorporates a lot of common features and I recommend you start there unless you want something unusual.

Answer (score 4):

They probably refer to the `QMainWindow` class.

Comment: ... which supports several qdockwidgets on each four side of the so called "main widget", which is usually the central document/view/whatnow of an application. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `mainWidget` is a `Qt 3` relic, and is no longer actively supported. Its `Qt 4` counterpart is the `QMainWindow` class.